# How to show application in task bar when executed?

Tags: vb.net, task

My application is a single instance application and is minimized to the Windows task bar when closed. However, one issue I have came across is that when my application is executed (example: through a shortcut on the desktop), while minimized to the task bar, the application is not resumed. Instead, another instance of the application opens, but quickly closes when it realizes another instance is already running.

I was wondering how I could have the window state of my application return to normal when the application is executed, when it is in the task bar (running in the background?)

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "task bar" do you actually mean "notification area", i.e. "system tray"?  The Task Bar shows an icon for all running apps while the try shows "background" applications.  When you say that it is a single-instance application, do you mean that you have checked the single-instance box in the project properties?  If so then you should handle the StartupNextInstance event of the application to be notified when the user tries to start another instance.  You can then restore your app's main form.

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding this helper class to your project.

```
Friend Class NativeMethods

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Friend Shared Function PostMessage(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wparam As IntPtr, ByVal lparam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Friend Shared Function RegisterWindowMessage(ByVal msg As String) As Integer
    End Function

    Friend Const HWND_BROADCAST As Integer = &HFFFF
    Friend Shared ReadOnly WM_RESTORE As Integer = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_RESTORE")

End Class
```

Then you'll need to create an entry point for your application. (Or modify if you already have one)

```
Public Class Program

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    <STAThread()> _
    Friend Shared Sub Main()
        If (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, True)) Then
            Application.EnableVisualStyles()
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
            Application.Run(New Form1()) '<- Replace this with an instance of your main form.
            Program.mutex.ReleaseMutex()
        Else
            NativeMethods.PostMessage(New IntPtr(NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST), NativeMethods.WM_RESTORE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
        End If
    End Sub

    Shared ReadOnly mutex As Mutex = New Mutex(True, "{A1CD1685-EFC9-4D63-BA66-CF2066857FC4}")

End Class
```

In you main form add the following code.

```
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Private Sub Restore()
        Me.Show()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If (m.Msg = NativeMethods.WM_RESTORE) Then
            Me.Restore()
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Finally, change the application startup object to sub main.

[How to: Change the Startup Object for an Application (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17k74w0c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**References**

http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html